# Onclick display Array Text Field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of text fields in my html page in array format with same field name.
I would like to alert the value when the nearby link is clicked.

```
<tr>
  <td>    
    <div id="myid">
      <input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a onclick="alert(document.getElementById('item_name').value))">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>    
    <div id="myid">
      <input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a onclick="alert(document.getElementById('item_name').value))">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I above sample, if i click first row then it should alert 1; next should alert 2

Comment: You don't have an `id="item_name"` attribute anywhere & you didn't close the `<a>` tags.

Comment: @Korikulum: I am using this array type field names for many purpose not only this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
<a onclick="alert(document.getElementById('item_name').value))">
```

into:

```
<a onclick="alert(this.parentNode.children[0].value)">LINK</a>
```

Explanation:

`this` will refer to the target element (the element clicked). From there you need to find the parent which is in `parentNode`. And from the parent take the first child element with `children[0]`. Voila, there you will find your value.

Comment: +1. But could you please tell how to the get the field value if it present inside a table row & division is split (updated my question)

Comment: @logan The trick was to traverse to the parent and then the first child. You can still do this, it's just one level deeper. So in the new case it would be `alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].children[0].value)`

Comment: Instead of calling it as this.parentNode, is it possible to call with the parent name id ? such as parentId.parentNode ?

Comment: Multiple parentNode is not working . if I have another <div> inside the <td>  as `<div id="myid">
abc
</div> <div id="myid">
      <input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a onclick="alert(document.getElementById('item_name').value))">
    </div>`

Comment: i may not know the item_name[] number of entries [0]. Its dynamic. Thats why i am struggling to get value. otherwise i would get it by easily calling its id.

Comment: You could find your way to the parent that contains both the `<input>` and `<a>`, and then do `getElementsByTagName()` like this: `alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value)` (Now quit changing your question :) )

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
document.getElementById('item_name')
```

Looks for an element with the attribute `id` equal to `item_name` but you don't have an `id` on your input. Change this:

```
<input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="1"/>
```

To this:

```
<input id="item_name" name="item_name[]" type="text" value="1"/>
```

Comment: what if i use same id name for all the input rows ?

Comment: Every element on the page must have a unique ID. You can do this by avoiding IDs entirely, which would deb better. See Rashmin Javiya's answer for that method. I was just trying to explain why your link didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not using JQuery anywhere in this code its just javascript.

Second you do not have attribute **ID** `item_name` anywhere. So you cant select an element with id `item_name` if no element has attribute id with that name. You need different type of selector or you need to add IDs to those input fields.

Try this:

Add class to all inputs with name `item_name`, also add class to your divs:

```
<input name="item_name[]" class="item_name" type="text" value="2" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('div.my_div_container a').on('click', function() {
   alert($(this).closest('div').find('input.item_name').val();

   //or you can use $(this).siblings('input.item_name').val();
}
```

Comment: what if i use same class name for all the input rows. I will have the same input name. and the Input fields are dynamicaly generated

Comment: @logan it will still work since you are looking at closest div element and finding that input within that div. You have only 1 input element inside that div

Comment: Thanks. But could you please tell how to the get the field value if it present inside a table row and the division is split. (updated my question)

Comment: @logan same way, add class to div and do same thing that I did, it should work.

Comment: fine.. what do you mean by div.my_div_container?

Comment: `Its not working..`I simply tried printing "hi". `<script>
$('div.my_div_container a').on('click', function() {
alert('hi');
}
</script>`

Comment: you need to add `div_container` class to your divs so it should be `<div class="div_container">`

Answer (score 0):

JQuery provides you with the `.siblings()` function which allows you find other elements in the same hierarchical level.
Read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Here is how you would use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("div.myid > a").click(function () { 
           alert($(this).siblings("input").val())
       });
   });
</script>
```